# Rails: template folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

Good day,

i tried some rails basics.

I want to create one template and use these in my layoutfile.

I created this file: views/template/sidebar.html.erb

```
 <% content_for (:sidebar) do %>

<ul>
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li>TEST</li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

And my layout file: views/layouts/test.html.erb

```
 <%= yield :sidebar %>
```

It appears: Template is missing

What goes wrong?

Comment: Does it also show an error message when you do not have the "yield :sidebar" in the layout?  It might not be finding the template for the action.  What is the file path for the template where it is looking?  That is the file it expects.

Comment: ah okay my call was wrong: layout "user_interface_trainerone".

Comment: now it is shown, but is doesnt show the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content_for needs to be in a view which is included.  You can put it into the view for the action.  Alternatively, (probably what you want to do) you can

```
<%= render :partial => "template/sidebar" %>
```

from the view for your action.  You will have to renamed the file from sidebar.html.erb to _sidebar.html.erb.

Comment: ok but in the book they explain to create the template with content_for and then you have to include this with <%= yield :sidebar %> in the layout

Comment: like here point 3.2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: @ddd you have to call "yield :sidebar" to yield to the template mark up associated with the symbol :sidebar.  The call to "content_for :sidebar" will make the association of the symbol :sidebar to the mark up in the block.  However, you need to run the code for "content_for :sidebar" which the way you had it was never getting called.  You need to put the content_for call into the view (also called the template) which gets called for the action.  It will not automatically find it in the views/template directory.

Comment: @ddd nothing in the guide is different than what I am saying.